# Django - Invalid Syntax with my view

Tags: python, django

I have the following view that gives me "invalid syntax (views.py, line 251)"

Line 251 is the "return HttpResponse(queryresults)"

What gives?

```
def test_queryjoin(request):
    jobmstquery = Jobmst.objects.filter(jobmst_id=3296)
    jobdtlquery = Jobdtl.objects.filter(jobdtl_id=3296)
    queryeset = chain(jobmstquery, jobdtlquery)
    queryresults = serializers.serialize("python", queryset, fields=('jobmst_id', 'jobmst_prntid', 'jobmst_name', 'jobdtl_cmd')
    return HttpResponse(queryresults)
```

My urls.py has the following -

```
url(r'^Blah/test/$', 'test_queryjoin'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of this line:

```
queryresults = serializers.serialize("python", queryset, fields=('jobmst_id', 'jobmst_prntid', 'jobmst_name', 'jobdtl_cmd'))
#                                                                                                                    here--^
```

Comment: I'm an idiot with fat fingers it would seem :)  That fixed it thanks!

Comment: @whoisearth - Eh, these things happen.  At least it was a simple typo. :)  Please don't forget to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) though.